# Oracle InProc server 5.0 Type Library in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oledb

I have a .net application which uses Oracle InProc server 5.0 Type Library(OracleInProcServer.dll) to connect with oracle database. Until now we were using Oracle 11g client but now we have to upgrade to Oracle 12c. I am not getting the OracleInProcServer.dll in COM components. Is it deprecated? If yes then what is the best alternative of this with minimum code changes in application. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

OO4O has been deprecated in 12c so we longer ship it. But it will still work fine - you just need to download the components, which are in ODAC.

Download that here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html